# extract links regex c#

Tags: c#, regex, capturing-group

I've been trying to solve these problem for last two hours but seems like I can't find any solution.

I need to extract links from an `HTML` file. There are 100+ links, but only 25 of them are valid.

Valid links are placed inside

`<td><a href=" (link) ">`

First I had (and still have) a problem with double quotes inside verbatim strings. So, I have replaced verbatim with "normal" strings so I can use \" for " but the problem is that this `Regex` I have written doesn't work

```
Match LinksTemp = Regex.Match(
                              htmlCode,
                              "<td><a href=\"(.*)\">",
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

as I get `"<td><a href="http://www.google.com">` as output instead of `http://www.google.com`

Anyone know how can I solve this problem and how can I use double quotes inside of verbatim strings (example @" <>"das"sa ")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaped double quotes sample: `@"some""test"`
Regex sample: `"<a href=\"(.*?)\">"`

```
    var match = Regex.Match(html, "<td><a href=\"(.*?)\">", 
RegexOptions.Singleline); //spelling error
    var url = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Also you may want to use `Regex.Matches(...)` instead of `Regex.Match(...)`

Comment: because groups[0] remember all string which is match to <td><a href=\"(.*?)\">. groups[1] cut text between (). If your regex will be: "<td><a (href)=\"(.*?)\">" then in groups[1] will be "href" and in groups[2] will be your www adres

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take every elements use code simply like this:

```
string htmlCode = "<td><a href=\" www.aa.pl \"><td> <a href=\" www.cos.com \"><td>";
Regex r = new Regex( "<a href=\"(.*?)\">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(htmlCode);

foreach ( Match m1 in mc ) {                
   MessageBox.Show( m1.Groups[1].ToString() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not parse this with an [HTML-parsing](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is good and fast HTML-Parsing. 
example:

```
   string HTML = "<td><a href='http://www.google.com'>";

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(HTML);
            HtmlNodeCollection a = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

            string url = a[0].GetAttributeValue("href", null);

            Console.WriteLine(url);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

you need import `using HtmlAgilityPack;`